# "Run keyword if"- want to perform double click on a button with this Built in function

Tags: robotframework

So, in brief, i have to perform click on one `button` and validate for one of the panels whether it is visible or not. So problem starts from here. sometimes it is visible after 2 clicks, and sometimes 1 as per some prerequisite(this is not a bug). Now i start with the solution like if the specified element is not visible then again click on that button and (2nd condition--)if it is visible then go with simple logic as it is.

```
 Run Keyword If    Element Should Not Be Visible    xpath=//div[@id='menu-container']    Click Button    css=[ng-click="toggleMode()"]
```

I am using Run keyword if-Built in function, Could anyone give me heads up how i can tackle this.

Comment: `run keyword if` requires an expression, not another keyword.

Comment: Yes Brian, I am aware of that but was very confused about implementation.So i send it like that. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the element is not visible and click, only if the status is True.

```
${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status     Element Should Not Be Visible    xpath=//div[@id='menu-container']
Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='True'    Click Button    css=[ng-click="toggleMode()"]
```

Comment: hi Cris, Thanks for your quick response but that is not solving my error. I am facing this failure report:                                          
 xpath=//div[@id='menu-container']' should not be visible, but it is.

Comment: Run Keyword and Return Status should return True or False, it should never fail... http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status

Comment: @cris-Thanks,i have tried that already and now it is executing fine, but now my test case is executing for both keywords "Run keyword if" and "Run keyword unless", any reasons for that?

Comment: Below is the 'code':                                                                                                                                                  Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='True'|Run Keyword And Return Status|    Check for Smart Plugins Panel
Run Keyword Unless|'${status}'=='False'|Click Button|css=[ng-click="toggleMode()"]|Check for Smart Plugins Panel

Comment: If you want to use Run Keyword Unless ... then it is Run Keyword Unless    '${status}'=='True'  (Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='True' and Run Keyword Unless    '${status}'=='False' are the same thing)

Comment: ok got it, so to move to the second set of action if '${status}'=='False' i should again put it in "Run Keyword If" Keyword. Correct me if i am wrong!!! Note: Intention is to simply run if else case but Else keyword is not available in robot framework i guess

Comment: Yes or you can use Run Keyword If     '${status}'=='True'... Run Keyword Unless     '${status}'=='True' ... both methods will have the same result, your choice :)